# SpringBoot Security Configuration not working as intended

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I have been trying to configure Spring Boot security in order to allow some urls without requiring an authentication and not allowing any other requests without an authentication. I am having trouble achieving this.

As per my understanding, anyRequest().authenticated() requires previously declared antMatchers to require authentication.

How is it possible to achieve my requirement.

My Http Security configuration

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {




        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,banner_top_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,banner_bottom_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,javascript_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,stylesheet_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,photos_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,transformed_photos_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,preview_url).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/**/*.html", "/static/favicon.ico", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.js.map", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.jpeg", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.ttf", "/**/*.json", "/**/*.woff", "/**/*.woff2", "/**/*.eot", "/**/*.svg").permitAll()// allows static content from resource folder
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll() // By default Security framework disables error pages (Unauthrorized)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtExceptionHandler,CorsFilter.class)
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))


                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().formLogin().disable();
    }
```

I assume that the below urls must be granted access without authentication.
*SIGN_UP_URL
banner_top_url
banner_bottom_url
javascript_url
stylesheet_url
photos_url
transformed_photos_url
preview_url*

The problem is this line : .anyRequest().authenticated()
If I remove it, then all the endpoints within the REST interface becomes available without authentication which I do not want.

Comment: What's the issue? .Adding anyRequest().authenticated() makes any request that does not match the previous antMatchers, require authentication

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you excluding the static resource files globally via web.ignoring?

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**"); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring-security allows to pass everything. You have to tell Spring what can pass and what cannot pass. By removing anyRequest().authenticated you are telling to spring that everything that matches the patterns you mentioned are allowed to go and with the rest do what you do by default, that means, proceed. Here you are Spring Security doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Spring-Working as intended. That being said,any antMAtchers will match the requestPath and not the resourcePath. An example is provided below.

```
*localhost:8080/image.jpg*
```

points at the root of the application which is *src/main/resources/static/image.jpg*

Now why is static used as a resource handler, that is because in the *staticResourceConfiguration.java* class I had the following lines
registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```